# How to redirect to dashboard if the login is correct

Tags: javascript

here validating login details. but how do i redirect to dashboard if login credentials are correct. And how do i avoid page refresh on submit with getting all the data from the form

```
 if(db.email == logEmail.value && db.password == logPass.value){
        window.location = '../html/dashboard';
        }else{
            console.log('username and password incorrect');
        }

        }
```

Comment: Please don't validate credentials client-side.

Comment: yeah but this is my assignment

Comment: can you answer this question Yuriy

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not post your entire form I would assume it goes something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function sampleLogin() {

            if (/* some condition false*/) {
            alert("cannot Submit form");
            window.location = ''; // your desired location
            return false; //<-- return false you can redirect here if you want
        }


    }
</script>

</head>


<body>
<form action="someUrl" method="post" onsubmit="sampleLogin()">
    User:
    <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
    <br>
    <br> Pass:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

If your submit method returns false it does not redirect or submits and you can use this to perform your own logic of redirecting.

Comment: i added window.location="<file location>" after return but nothing happens